# Grassman Identity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A, B and B' be subspace of a vector space of V of finite dimensions for which $A\cap B = A \cap B'$ , A + B = A + B' and B subset of B'. Then B = B'. Hint (Use Grassman's Identity)

I don't know how to start ta proof, or how to manipulate ta grassman identity

Comment: Maybe try to describe what you have tried and where you're stuck

Comment: The point you want to make is that $B\subseteq B'$ (given) and $\dim(B)=\dim(B')$ (result from Grassman's Identity) implies $B=B'$. So if you can show that $\dim(B)=\dim(B')$ you have your result.

Comment: I don't know how to start the proof.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh. Ok thank youuu

Comment: No problem. Perhaps for future reference, try to include maybe an attempt, reflection or at least the theory and definitions, that you're working with, in your question, then people will be more likely to try and give you hints and/or answers :)